# How do i extract certain values in a row satisfying a condition in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame looking something like this -

[image]

Now , how do i extract all the elements in row A having a value greater than 2 ?

In the above case it would be the value 2.706850

I did something like this-

`df.loc['A']>2`

But i got a series containing Boolean Values something like this -

[image]

**What should i do to get 2.706850 as the output ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Recommended solution

You can index the dataframe with the conditional expression and the series label itself:

```
df.loc[df.loc['A'] > 2, 'A']
```

---

#### Old answer, not recommended

> Avoid using this approach as it encourages chained assignment. Check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas/53954986#53954986) for more details

You just need to index back into the series with your boolean mask as follows:

```
>>> df.loc['A'][df.loc['A'] > 2]
F    2.706850
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This isn't a great answer, it encourages chained assignment. You will instead want: `df.loc[df['A'] > 2, 'A']` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986 cc @AdityaKulkarni

Comment: No worries, this is likely a duplicate of something else. Just amend your answer and I'd be happy to upvote. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Below are tried OK

```
df.loc['A',df.loc['A']>2]
df.loc['A'][df.loc['A']>2]
```